# Copying large files using Rsync on Mac between a NAS and a local hard drive

Tags: macos, backup, rsync

I am running a regular backup using Rsync for one of my data servers. I am backing up the data which is on my Synology NAS Storage to an External Hard drive over the network and using a gigabit connection. I have got around 4TB worth of data to backup every day and I am using the following rsync command:

```
rsync --progress --delete -aE /source /destination
```

but using this command is taking very long for the data to backup. Can someone please suggest a quick way of doing it through Rsync.

Comment: I am backing up the data which is on my Synology NAS Storage to an External Hard drive over the network and using a gigabit connection. I know its going to take few hours but i kicked off the backup on Thursday Morning and its still running. Any suggestion to make it better?

Comment: @JakeGould Yes thats correct i am running rsync command through terminal using Mac. Synology NAS is my source data drive and the external drive is my destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state this:

> I am running a regular backup using Rsync for one of my data servers.
>   I am backing up the data which is on my Synology NAS Storage to an
>   External Hard drive over the network and using a gigabit connection.

The problem here is not Rsync or network infrastructure but rather the framework of the procedure you are dealing with.

When you run Rsync—or do any file system operations—on a local disk, the OS has direct access to that the file system information to do whatever it has to do.

But if you are running your command off of your Mac OS X machine which has a network connection to them copy to an external hard drive this is what happens:

- When you run the command on your Mac OS X machine, what happens is the OS actually has to reach out over the network to the network volume *before* it makes any copies to simply get basic file system info since none of that info is local to your OS’s file system.
- Only *after* that file system info is finally received by whatever process requested it are those file system actions actually executed to act on the data.

So using a setup like this will seemingly take forever.  The better option is to somehow login to your Synology NAS and then have it connect to that external hard drive as a remote share and then run the Rsync command—or some equivalent—directly from the Synology NAS itself. A rough starrier could be something like this:

- You create a network share on your Mac OS X machine that is mapped to the external hard drive.
- You setup login credentials on the Synology NAS via the DSM software interface.
- Once you have the Synology NAS setup to mount the network share on that  Mac OS X machine that is mapped to the external hard drive, then on that Synology NAS run some Rsync command.

I have worked with Synology’s DSM software in the past and I know there is either some built in backup software on the system that is either explicitly Rsync or something that works like Rsync. But in general, you need the Synology NAS itself to manage the process if you want to get real speed out of this setup.

Comment: You are right actually i was thinking to run the backup from synology directly instead. Your suggestion is great to run the rsync command from synology nas. I will give it a go and see how it goes. Thanks alot for your help on this.